# Group and add values from JSON object

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I'm having trouble grouping and then adding some values I get from JSON returned from an AJAX query.

The data comes back like this:

```
0: Object 
  count: 12
  grp: 1
  id: "1"
1: Object 
  count: 21
  grp: 2
  id: "3"
2: Object 
  count: 48
  grp: 3
  id: "4"
3: Object 
  count: 51
  grp: 2
  id: "5"
```

For `grp` there are five possible options (groups): 1,2,3,4,5. What I want to do is add together all the `count` values for each specific group. That is, add all `grp` 1 `count` values together, all the `grp` 2 `count` values together, and so on.

What's the best way to do this? I can't figure out an `each` or anything that quite works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var counts = {};
$.each(data, function(index, item){
    var sum = counts[item.grp] || 0;
    counts[item.grp] = sum + item.count;
});

console.log(counts);
# {1: 12, 2: 72, 3: 48}
```

Comment: Good idea to use `grp` as the index for the counts array.

Comment: This is getting me close, but I'm getting back `Object {1: NaN, 2: NaN, 3: NaN, 4: NaN, 5: NaN}`. If I do `console.log(item.count);` within the `each` it returns all the count values, so I can't figure out why I'd be getting these `NaN`s

Comment: Sorry that was my bad, I've just updated. It's because `counts[item.grp]` returns `undefined` until you've set a value, so  `+=` straight away was returning NaN

Comment: Yep...thanks! The edit worked. The numbers returned are wrong (returns more than what's in my database), but I think that's because I'm getting bad data in the JSON.

Comment: Nope...just tested...it's not your code. It works perfectly. It's my crappy query that I have to figure out.